# Is it possible to calculate the ganttgroup progress automatically?

Tags: pgfgantt

Is it possible to calculate the progress of the ganttgroup automatically. If the Task 1 progress changes than the ganttgroup progress will be recalculated automatically?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}




\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\mddefault{mc}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bc}

\sffamily
\begin{document}    
    \centering \Large\textbf{Time Table}
    \begin{center}  
    \noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0cm, y=0cm]   
        \begin{ganttchart}[
                canvas/.append style={  fill=none, 
                                        draw=black!5, 
                                        line width=1pt},                                    
                hgrid style/.style={    draw=black!5, 
                                        line width=1pt},                                    
                vgrid={*1{  draw=black!5, 
                            line width=1pt}},                       
                today=2,            
                today rule/.style={
                    draw=black!64,
                    dash pattern=on 3.5pt off 4.5pt,
                    line width=1.5pt
                },          
                today label font=\small\bfseries,
                title/.style={draw=none, fill=none},
                title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
                title label node/.append style={below=7pt},
                include title in canvas=false,
                bar label font=\mdseries\small\color{black!70},
                bar label node/.append style={left=1cm},
                bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=black!63},
                bar incomplete/.append style={fill=barblue},
                bar progress label font=\mdseries\footnotesize\color{black!70},
                group incomplete/.append style={fill=groupblue},
                group left shift=0,
                group right shift=0,
                group height=.5,
                group peaks tip position=0,
                group label node/.append style={left=1cm},
                group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
                link label font=\scriptsize\bfseries,
                link label node/.append style={below left=-2pt and 0pt},
                ]{1}{52}

        \ganttgroup[progress=80]{Big task}{1}{52} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=90]{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
        \ganttbar[progress=70]{Task 2}{2}{4} \\
      \end{ganttchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added a minimal example.